# PHP preg_replace - www or http://

Tags: php, url, preg-replace, spaces

Really stuck on what seems to be something simple. I have a chatbox/shoutbox where there may be arbitrary URLs entered. I want to find each individual URL (separated by spaces) and wrap it in tags.

Example: `Harry you're a http://google.com wizard!` = `Harry you're a $lhttp://google.com$l wizard!`

Example: `Harry you're a http://www.google.com wizard!` = `Harry you're a $lhttp://www.google.com$l wizard!`

Example: `Harry you're a www.google.com wizard!` = `Harry you're a $lwww.google.com$l wizard!`

Sorry if this is a daft question; I'm just trying to make something work and I'm no php expert :(

Comment: the regex should be `/(http:\/\/)(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/`

Comment: When I use this with: $chat = preg_replace($old_words, $new_words, $chat);

I get $lhttp://$l

where $oldwords is: '/(http:\/\/)(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/'

and $new_words is: '$l$1$l'

Comment: try to add this comment in your question instead

Comment: You have a syntax error, it should be `You're a wizard, Harry`

Comment: I see what you did there, i like it ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is an interesting article about a [URL regular expression](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls).  In PHP this would look like:

```
$pattern = "/(?i)\b((?:https?:\/\/|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/";

$inp = "Harry you're a http://google.com wizard!";
$text = preg_replace($pattern, "[supertag]$1[/supertag]", $inp);
```

And of course replace `[supertag]` and `[/supertag]` with the appropriate values.

Comment: If this worked for you please mark it as the accepted answer so that it will help others who run into it.

Comment: When I copy/paste your pattern, I get somehow (at the very end) `«»“”‘’` these quotes in the middle transformed into normal quotes.
I use dreamweaver. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: this transforms ALL urls and not just the ones surrounded by spaces. So it breaks links where the user actually entered html enclosed urls.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use what's called a [Regular Expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

You should write a regular expression, and then use one of PHP's various [regexp functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php) to do what you want.

In this case, you should probably use the preg_replace() function, which finds a string that matches your regular expression and replaces it as you specify.

The regular expression you are looking for is particularly tricky to write, as URLs can come in many forms, but I found an expression which should do the trick:

```
$text = "derp derp http://www.google.com derp";
$text = preg_replace(
  '@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@',
  '[yourtag]$1[/yourtag]',
  $text
);
echo $text;
```

This will output:

```
derp derp [yourtag]http://www.google.com[/yourtag] derp
```

You can see that the `preg_replace()` function found the URL (and it will find multiple) in `$text`, and put the tags I specified around it.

Comment: This is along the right lines and will do the job i guess, thank you!

The only issue is, if the url does not have a space before it it still tries to work with it, any way to only work with the url if its separate from any other words?

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = " Helloooo try thiss http://www.google.com and www.youtube.com :D it works :)";

$text = preg_replace('#http://[a-z0-9._/-]+#i', '<a href="$0">$0</a>', $text);

$regex = "#[ ]+(www.([a-z0-9._-]+))#i";

$text = preg_replace($regex," <a href='http://$1'>$1</a>",$text);

echo $text;
```