# edit urls in string before echoing?

Tags: php, mysql, function, dom, href

not sure how it can be done, but how can I edit the urls in a string before echoing results from the db?

**basically:**

the string coming from db:

> Hello, I am Terry. I like using `<a href="http://www.twitter.com">Twitter</a>`, but I prefer using `<a href="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a>`. I like posting blogs on my website at `<a href="http://www.mycoolsite.com">My Cool Site</a>`, and I enjoying playing sports.

but I want to echo out:

> Hello, I am Terry. I like using `<a href="http://www.somepage.com/home?url=http://www.twitter.com">Twitter</a>`, but I prefer using `<a href="http://www.somepage.com/home?url=http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a>`. I like posting blogs on my website at `<a href="http://www.somepage.com/home?url=http://www.mycoolsite.com">My Cool Site</a>`, and I enjoying playing sports.

eg: Replace `http://www.twitter.com` in href with `http://www.somepage.com/home?url=http://www.twitter.com`

Comment: Take a look at this questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165552/php-preg-replace-www-or-http

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are actually looking for,

```
<?php   /** PHP, JavaScript and HTML/CSS mixed-code sample */

$string = 'Hello, I am Terry. I like using <a href="http://www.twitter.com">Twitter</a>, but I prefer using <a href="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a>. I like posting blogs on my website at <a href="http://www.mycoolsite.com">My Cool Site</a>, and I enjoying playing sports.';    
$myurl = "http://www.somepage.com/home?url=";

$result = preg_replace('/(<a[^>]*href[\s]*=["|\'])(.*?["|\'])/', "$1$myurl$2", $string);

echo $result;
?>
```

You can try that code on phpfiddle.org it's working. Let me know if you need anything change in that.

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
<?php
$string = 'Hello, I am Terry. I like using <a href="http://www.twitter.com">Twitter</a>, but I prefer using <a href="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a>. I like posting blogs on my website at <a href="http://www.mycoolsite.com">My Cool Site</a>, and I enjoying playing sports.';
$myurl = "http://www.somepage.com/home?url=";

preg_match_all('/(<a[^>]*href[\s]*=)["|\'](.*?)["|\']/', $string, $result, PREG_SET_ORDER);

for($i=0;$i<count($result);$i++){
    $string = str_replace($result[$i][0], $result[$i][1] .'"'. $myurl . urlencode($result[$i][2]) .'"'  ,$string);
}

?>
<!--<textarea><?php echo $string; ?></textarea>-->
<?php echo $string; ?>
```

Comment: wait, how can I urlencode() the link from $string before adding it to $myurl ?

Comment: oh right. You then need to change the preg_replace with preg_match. Wait let me update my answer in a bit so that you can urlencode links.

Comment: Actually it needs a little change in regex and the way we did it at first. In preg_replace you can't execute urlencode so we need to first find all matches using preg_match and then urlencode the links. And yes finally it would give you entire links like this,
http://www.somepage.com/home?url=original_url_encoded

Comment: yes that's what i'm trying to do, the code you gave works fine when a link is clicked on my local server but then throws a 403 forbidden online when the link is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string="Hello, I am Terry. I like using <a href="http://www.somepage.com/home?url=http://www.twitter.com">Twitter</a>, but I prefer using <a href="http://www.somepage.com/home?url=http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a>. I like posting blogs on my website at <a href="http://www.somepage.com/home?url=http://www.mycoolsite.com">My Cool Site</a>, and I enjoying playing sports."

preg_replace('/<a href="([^"]*)" >/','<a href="someurl?url=$1" >',$string)
```

Comment: before you go do you know how I can urlencode() the link in the string before combining the two links?

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty way to get it done,

```
$new_string = str_replace('href="', 'href="http://www.somepage.com/home?url=', $old_string);
```